# How can I do space-around for divs within a div without using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `div` with 3 `divs`. The inner `divs` are squares. I want to do what the `justify-content:space-around` does without using flex. Also, if I want to use `space-around` how do I reduce the margin between the elements. I feel they are too far away from each other.

```css
.squareContainer{
  overflow: hidden;
  width:1200px;
  background-color:black;
}

.sqC{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #7F5F01;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
}

.floatClass{
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="squareContainer">
   <div class="floatClass sqC">
      <h2>SQUARE</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="floatClass sqC">
       <h2>SQUARE</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="floatClass sqC">
        <h2>SQUARE</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try `.sqC {     margin: 5px 50px; }` - is that what you're going for?

Comment: @MichaelCoker no.. can i do it without margin? when i resize the window it's all messed up

Comment: Then use relative units. remove the width from `.squareContainer` and use `margin: 5px 1.5%;` on `.sqC`. Or use media queries. Why don't you want to use a media query? This is what they're for - resizing things with fixed units that need to behave responsively.

Comment: @MichaelCoker. i thought using `margin` in this way is bad practice.. i guess it isn't. thanks.

Comment: It's definitely  not bad practice. It's the way bootstrap's grid works before v4 (since v4 uses flex). Percentage based widths with percentage based margins. If that works I can submit it as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use fixed margins to evenly space the elements out.

```css
.squareContainer{
  overflow: hidden;
  width:1200px;
  background-color:black;
}

.sqC{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #7F5F01;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px 50px; 
}

.floatClass{
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="squareContainer">
   <div class="floatClass sqC">
      <h2>SQUARE</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="floatClass sqC">
       <h2>SQUARE</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="floatClass sqC">
        <h2>SQUARE</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

Or you can use relative units that will be responsive

```css
.squareContainer{
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:black;
}

.sqC{
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #7F5F01;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px 1.5%; 
}

.floatClass{
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="squareContainer">
   <div class="floatClass sqC">
      <h2>SQUARE</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="floatClass sqC">
       <h2>SQUARE</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="floatClass sqC">
        <h2>SQUARE</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use `display: inline-block;`?

Add `text-align: center;` and `display: block;` to `squareContainer`.

Also add `display: inline-block;` to the `sqC`class and remove `float: left`.

```css
.squareContainer{
  overflow: hidden;
  width:1200px;
  background-color:black;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.sqC{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #7F5F01;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.floatClass{
 // float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="squareContainer">
   <div class="floatClass sqC">
      <h2>SQUARE</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="floatClass sqC">
       <h2>SQUARE</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="floatClass sqC">
        <h2>SQUARE</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the margin properties however you like:

```
.sqC {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #7F5F01;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px 2px;
}
```

Comment: can i do it without margin? when i resize the window it's all messed up

Comment: do you stack these divs after resize?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you modify your margin?

```css
.squareContainer{
  overflow: hidden;
  width:1200px;
  background-color:black;
}

.sqC{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #7F5F01;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1px;
}

.floatClass{
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="squareContainer">
   <div class="floatClass sqC">
      <h2>SQUARE</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="floatClass sqC">
       <h2>SQUARE</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="floatClass sqC">
        <h2>SQUARE</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can i do it without margin? when i resize the window it's all messed up

Comment: well that is another probleme.  But, You can add some @media sections to your CSS to modify the margin with the screen size.  `@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 699px) {

  .floatClass sq {      
   margin:2px;     
   }

}`  Adding more sections like this and more details to it will make your code responsive.

Comment: hmm. yeah. i was hoping to find a way to do it without using the @media thing and margin.